# Unable to resolve the Spring property value with JSF

Tags: spring, jsf

I try to integrate JSF with Spring, so I have very simple code:

Manged Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userData")
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String message;

   public String getMessage() {
      return message;
   }

   public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
   }

   public String getGreetingMessage(){
      return getMessage();
   }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="messageService"   class="test.UserData">
      <property name="message" value="Hello World" />        
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
    <application>
        <!-- SpringBeanFacesELResolver -->
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

home.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>Spring with JSF</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
    #{userData.greetingMessage}
   </h:body>
</html>
```

The problem, when I run the home.xhtml I don't get the get the value of massage!!
it display only empty page. It seem it can't get the value of the message property from the ApplicationContext.xml.

What is the wrong in my method and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're letting Spring manage the JSF beans using [SpringFacesELResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver), JSF annotations will not be necessary.

```
public class UserData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
      return message;
    }

   public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
   }

}
```

And, in your *applicationContext.xml* (note the [session scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)):

```
<bean id="userData" class="test.UserData" scope="session">
  <property name="message" value="Hello World" />        
</bean>
```

Accessing it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>Spring with JSF</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
    #{userData.message}
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Should give a *Hello World* HTML output, if the JSF servlet properly configured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It fixed only if use sessionCope in the applicationContext.xml instead of in JSF bean class?? Or you mean also I should use #{userData.getMessage} directly always (getter)??

Comment: @R.Almoued the getter was a typo, I've fixed it. I mean you have to refer to the spring bean, not the JSF one. You let spring manage the beans, not JSF.